# how to add new column dynamically based off the values in other columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, dynamic

I am displaying my GridView dynamically but I want to add a new column called Not POD. 
You can see in the image the columns Jobs and POD. I want to create a new column that will equal to the Jobs minus the POD. So for example in the first row the new column should display 1 (14 - 13).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a TemplateField to your gridview, after all the BoundFields. Example

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Non POD">
      <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Jobs")) - Convert.ToInt32(Eval("POD")) %>'></asp:Label>                            
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I don't have any BoundFields. The columns are being created dynamically.

Comment: If you're creating them dynamically in codebehind then what's stopping you from creating the column you want the same way ? If your gridview is using a datasource then set AutoGenerateColumns to false and you'll be able to add BoundField and TemplateField items in asp.